# Evaluation of LDA

Tags: topic-models

I am looking for a C++/Java implementation for computing the perplexity of held-out document in Latent Dirichlet allocation. Can anybody suggest useful links?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some googling about [UMass MALLET](http://mallet.cs.umass.edu/topics.php) (Java) library.

You can use its functions to calculate the log probability of each document, $log(p(\mathbf{w}_d))$, in your hold-out set, and then from that you can easily calculate perplexity according to the formula from the [LDA paper](https://www.cs.princeton.edu/~blei/papers/BleiNgJordan2003.pdf):

$$ perplexity(D_{hold out}) = 
\exp({-\frac{\sum_{d=1}^{M} log(p(\mathbf{w}_d))}{\sum_{d=1}^{M} N_d}}) $$

where $M$ is the # of documents, $N_d$ is the number of words or tokens per document, and $\mathbf{w}_d$ is the sequence of words in document $d$.

I found a forum post that describes some of the steps to doing this:
http://t3527.ai-mallet-development.aitalk.info/model-perplexity-t3527.html

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

You might find [this](http://www.quora.com/Natural-Language-Processing/What-is-the-fastest-and-easiest-to-use-implementation-for-LDA-training-and-inference-on-a-very-large-corpus) link useful - it's a good place to start searching for a suitable library, since many are listed here.